# Good design using CoreData?

Tags: core-data, model, nsmanagedobject

To use CoreData many developers inherit model objects from `NSManagedObject`.

But what if I wanted to keep my model objects independent from the storage mechanism that is being used (maybe i will reuse them in a project where I dont need persistency at all)?

My solution so far has been to create for each model class a class inheriting from `NSManagedObject` that has a reference to the model object and loads and stores it.

Whats a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to work with Core Data is to inherit your model objects from NSManagedObject. You can then control whether to persist or not from the Context, like TechZen pointed.

If you still insist on not inheriting your model classes from NSManagedObject, it can be of help to combine protocols and categories as described by RyanR. However, you will have in my opinion a big overhead creating protocols, categories and duplicating classes.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way of creating entities which can be persisted by Core Data and also used completely disconnected from Core Data. Anything which inherits from NSManagedObject carries some baggage with it, not least of which is that you can't serialize it without some custom code for each object.

You could create some protocols that represent each of your entities, which your Core Data managed objects conform to, as do your standalone objects. You can use categories on NSObjects which conform only to your entity protocol to implement behavior shared by Core Data and standalone entities. By making the category only apply to classes which conform to your entity protocol, you prevent the category from being applied to every NSObject (very bad). Instead it only applies to classes you implement which conform to that category. This is the only way I've found to share some code between Core Data entities and standalone entities.

To prevent loosing any changes you make to your Core Data entities every time you change your model, I use [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) to regenerate the entities instead of XCode. That lets me separate the Core Data-specific stuff from whatever customizations I need on the entities (such as applying the protocol for the entity). If you're on XCode 3, mogenerator includes a plugin that handles XCode integration. If you're on XCode 4, the plugin doesn't work, but with the help of another developer on the DevForums I [wrote up a tutorial](http://www.esenciadev.com/2011/05/mogen-and-xcode4-integration/) on getting mogenerator to work.

Comment: +1 You can actually use managed objects without a context, you just don't get any of the "managed" because the context is the actual manager that makes sure all the reciprocal relationships are set and forces all the validations. That tremendous loss of functionality makes it rather pointless to use managed objects absent the context.

Comment: You are describing a very interesting solution combining protocols + categories, which I guess would be useful when your client needs to interact with objects having a common interface (something like Proxy pattern?). So you are basically saying that my approach of duplicating the model objects is just fine? Thanks for info on mogenerator

Comment: All you're duplicating if you follow this pattern are data storage (ivars) - the behavior of your objects is shared through the categories. I've used it successfully in several large-ish line of business apps I've written for clients. Performance is fantastic, and it's very easy to maintain the business rules since they're consolidated.

Answer (score 1):

> But what if I wanted to keep my model
>   objects independent from the storage
>   mechanism that is being used (maybe i
>   will reuse them in a project where I
>   dont need persistency at all)?

With Core Data, persistence is just an option, it is not required because Core Data is not primarily a persistence API. Instead, it is an object graph management API intended to provide the complete model layer of a Model-View-Controller design app. It's true function is managing objects in a graph in order to accurate model/simulate real-world objects, conditions or events and the relationships between them.

You change persistence options at the level of the persistent store coordinator. You have the option of using a sqlite store, a binary store, a xml plist store or an in-memory store which, as the name suggest, is not really a "persistent" store at all. You also have the option of writing your own custom store. See [Atomic Store Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AtomicStore_Concepts/Introduction/Introduction.html) for details.

You really need the managed object context to get any value from Core Data.  Instead of naming it "NSManagedObjectContext" they should have named it a "NSManagedObjectManager" because that is were all the automatic object graph maintenance is done. If you wanted to duplicate that functionality, you'd have to basically write you own manager class.

In my opinion, the best way to provide insurance for the kind of flexibility you seek it to write in a serialization method to a common data format such as JSON. Then if you need to switch to another persistence option, you can just convert the Core Data object graph to JSON and send to whatever wherever.

However, I really wouldn't bother unless you already know for certain that such a functionality will be needed. It very, very rarely is. It's better to code only for known requirements and then only burn the time for new requirements when they actually show up.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Its fine that you can control from some other class whether you persist or not. But still, would you always inherit your model classes from NSManagedObject? Maybe I'm being too conservative, but I don't feel comfortable making my classes inherit from an external class. Why would I use CoreData at all in another project where I dont need persistency nor this object graph you describe. Maybe Im beeing a bit ignorant about how powerful that is. Do you personally always have this need?

Comment: Core Data is not primarily a persistence API. It is an API for creating the entire model layer of a Model-View-Controller design. Persistence is just an option. It's the recommended model layer tool for the API. There is no particular reason NOT to use it when writing for mac or ios. Under MacOS it lets you create entire apps without writing code.

Comment: Core Data is a great object graph management system, without a doubt. But the fact that you can't (out of the box) serialize an object which inherits from NSManagedObject cripples it for use disconnected from the Core Data stack, IMO.

Comment: @RyanR -- Well, yes. These are ***managed*** objects. There is no particular reason to use NSManagedObject subclasses if you don't want to manage them. The graph itself is a key component of the data. There is not much point of saving individual objects and losing the graph data. It would be trivial to serialize the objects if you needed to but there is really little point. I'm not sure why you wouldn't use the Core Data stack if it was available. It's very, very flexible.

Comment: The question was how to share/reuse code between an NSManagedObject and an NSObject completely disconnected from Core Data, without including and of Core Data.